# Software installation startup-script via GPO

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files, gpo

We would like to deploy a few applications to clients via GPO. The install packages are .exe and not .msi, hence we are not able to distribute via the normal "Computer Configuration\Policies\Software Settings\Software Installation" policy.

Hence, we thought about using a startup script under "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts\Startup". However, the software should only install once and not each startup. Hence, we thought that the results should be recorded in a text file, which is then read on startup and if the file exists, then don't install. At the moment our very basic script looks line this:

```
IF EXIST "c:\vcredist_2010_x86.txt" GOTO END
IF EXIST "c:\vcredist_2010_x64.txt" GOTO END

:32-bit
if exist %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 goto 64-bit
\\servername\sharename\C++Redist\2010\vcredist_2010_x86.exe /passive /norestart
echo "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x86" > "c:\vcredist_2010_x86.txt"
goto END

:64-bit
\\servername\sharename\C++Redist\2010\vcredist_2010_x64.exe /passive /norestart
echo "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x64" > "c:\vcredist_2010_x64.txt"

:END
```

Works just fine, but we would like to refine it a little. Would be nice to have just 1 text file which is written to (i.e. c:\software-dist.txt) and per installation the relevant line (Software Name) be added to this file. On startup, the script should check to see if the line exists, if yes then don't install, if no then install the software.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
:CheckOS
if exist %systemdrive%\"Program Files (x86)" (
set bit=x64
) else (
set bit=x86
)

:Check1
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="softwarename" goto Check2
)

\\servername\sharename\vcredist_2010_%bit%.exe /passive /norestart
echo softwarename >>C:\software-dist.txt

:Check2
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="Microsoft Visual 2008" goto :Check3
)

\\servername\sharename\C++Redist\vcredist_2008_%bit%.exe /passive /norestart
echo Microsoft Visual 2008 >>C:\software-dist.txt

:Check3
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"==Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable %bit% goto :Check4
)

\\servername\sharename\2005\vcredist_2005_%bit%.exe /passive /norestart
echo Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable %bit% >>C:\software-dist.txt

:Check4
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"==Microsoft .NET Framework 4 goto :END
)

\\servername\sharename\dotNet4.exe
echo Microsoft .NET Framework 4 >>C:\software-dist.txt

:END
```

That will check the single txt file to see if it contains a line with the name of the software. If it does, it exits, if not it installs it and adds itself into the list when it's finished.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Bali. Not sure what this line means:

    if "%%a"=="softwarename" exit >nul

Surely I need to add something like:

    if "%%a"=="Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x64" exit >nul

Comment: Yeah you do, that was just a placeholder :)

Comment: Just a thought, would it not be better to do the 64-bit / 32-bit check before? Any ideas of a 'nicer' check?

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference where you made the check, but I've edited my answer to make the install a bit more efficient.

Comment: Great - thanks. If I wanted to build some more software checks within this script, could I replace the "exit >nul" with a "goto :placeholder" ?

Comment: Great. I need to check for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005, 2008 & 2010 Redistributable, along with .NET Framework 4 - if they don't exist, then install them. I could do this using my GOTO :Placeholder way - or have your a better idea.

Comment: Your probably best using the placeholder way, there are other ways but they won't make life easier when it's a startup script.

Comment: Great. The check for the "softwarename" - does this have to be the complete name within the line, or can it be part of the name (i.e. "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable" instead of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x86").

Comment: It would have to be the full name, as it is based on exact string matches.

Comment: OK. Does our 32-bit/64-bit check then need to come before the check in the softare-dist.txt - otherwise I should not write "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - %bit%" to the text file. Or should I put 2 checks after another: <code>if "%%a"=="Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x64" goto Check2</code> then on the next line<code>if "%%a"=="Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x86" goto Check2</code>

Comment: Just an idea. I put the <code>if exist %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64...</code> lines at the top of the batch file. Then I have the variable "bit". Then change the check string line to <code>if "%%a"=="Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - %bit%" goto Check2</code>

Comment: I have tested your script. The echo of the name of the software within the text file gets duplicated every time the script is run. Somehow the line <code>if "%%a"=="softwarename" exit >nul</code> does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: After a little more troubleshooting, I think the problem is to do with the fact that my softwarename contains spaces (i.e. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable). If the softwarename is a single word, it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Somehow the line <code>for /f %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (</code> does not work if the softwarename contains spaces. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: You should be able to quote the `%%a` in the `do` code like `"%%a"`

Comment: Should it look like this: <code>for /f "%%a" in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (</code>

Comment: This works just fine: <code>for /f %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (</code> along with <code>if %%a=="softwarename" goto Check2</code>. However, if softwarename has more than one word (i.e. "software name") - then it does not work. Do we have to use tokens & delims ?

Comment: Ah right, yeah you will have to use delims `for /f "delims=" %%a in etc`

Comment: Line looks like this: <code>for /f "delims= " %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (</code>, but still does not work

Comment: There's no space between the `delims=` and the `"` :)

Comment: Could you post the entire batch file you are using into your question, just so I can see what the latest script you are using looks like, thanks.

Comment: The edit got revoked! Check out [link](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/test.cmd)

Comment: It's ok, I got it, it got revoked because they wouldn't have seen that I asked for you to post it. See my answer, I edited it a bit, but just fill in the dirs and it should work fine. If this works we could look at using a text file with the software names in it, so you don't have to hardcode them in the batch, and just loop over them as well.

Comment: Sorry, does not work :O(... Try it out. For Testing, I remove the `\\servername\sharename\2005\vcredist_2005_%bit%.exe /passive /norestart`

Comment: Put a `pause >nul` at the end and read through the console to see where it is going wrong, hopefully it should give some sort of error.

Comment: I just ran the script on my machine, only replacing the software installs with echo's instead, and it worked fine, can you find any errors? Try using `start` at the front of the software installs `start \\servername\sharename\2005\vcredist_2005_%bit%.exe /passive /norestart`

Comment: The results of the test.cmd I previously posted. I have totally removed the software install lines - I just want the script to correctly update the text file. [First run](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/test-echo-1st-run.txt) - the software-dist.txt does not exist. [Second run](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/test-echo-2nd-run.txt) - the software-dist.txt has all software names within.

Comment: I simply ran the test.cmd twice - no change to the original [test.cmd](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/test.cmd). The first run is the scenario that none of the software is installed (i.e. the script creates the software-dist.txt and adds the relevant software names. The second run then checks the software-dist.txt... the problem is, it does not work, that means the software-dist.txt gets updated with another 4 lines of software.

Comment: I'm not sure then, it runs fine on my machine. The script in that link isn't the same as my updated one, but if you have already tried that then it might be worth asking that as a different question, at least you have something to work with now.

Comment: The [script](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/test.cmd) is now exactly the same as what you have posted in your answer (refresh browser cache). It does not work.

Comment: It works for me, it writes the software names that it would have installed that weren't in the software-dist file into it, it must be a something specific to your machine, maybe permissions to root of C:\ ? Ask another question specific to why this won't work, maybe someone else will have some more ideas about it.

Comment: I have full admin rights to my machine and it can't be a permissions thing, 'coz the software-dist.txt gets updated. However, it always gets updated with each run. Does your software-dist.txt only get updated once - that means it only contains 4 lines of text?

Comment: You would have to delete it after each run as the `>>` will append, so the software can be written in. I ran it once and it worked fine. Try running it on a fresh copy with only the software names, then you can sort out the updating thing when it's working.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the `goto Check2` was to bypass the `echo Software name >> C:\software-dist.txt` if the **Software name** was found within the software-dist.txt text file

Comment: That's a good point actually. Well, it's time to debug it. Start by running each for loop chunk on it's own and find out where it is going wrong, if you find an issue in one it's likely it will apply to them all. As I said before though, this works fine for me.

Comment: I have created a [new call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125706/software-installation-script) to troubleshoot this. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Cool, hopefully someone will be able to tell what's happening, no worries.

Comment: Question answered - check out the script [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125706/software-installation-script).