# Software installation script

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, batch-file, goto

I am having a problem with the following script, which we wish to use as part of a login script in order to check if software has been installed, and if not, install it:

```
:STEP1
for /f "delims= " %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="Softwarename1" goto STEP2
)
\\server\share\software1.exe
echo Softwarename1 >> C:\software-dist.txt

:STEP2
for /f "delims= " %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="Software name 2" goto END
)
\\server\share\software2.exe /Q
echo Software name 2 >> C:\software-dist.txt

:END
```

The code is STEP1 works just fine - here the name of the software is a single word "**Softwarename1**". However, the code in STEP2 does not work - here the name of the software is written as 3 separate words "**Software name 2**" (a space between each word). Each time the script is run, the *c:\software-dist.txt* gets updated with another line of "**Software name 2**".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added a tag indicating the programming language. That will bring your question to the attention of people who can answer it faster.

Comment: Yeah, you're tokenizing the file with a space delimiter. So you'll get a "Software" token, a "name" token and a "2" token but never all three together...It would help if you posted the format of your text file.

Comment: Sorry, just a simple Windows DOS batch file (.bat / .cmd). Tags updated. Sometimes the software name will have more than 3 words (tokens) - how can I get the script to work with such names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lc pointed out the problem in his comment, but didn't explicitly provide the obvious solution.

You are setting the token delimiter to a space. You need to disable the DELIMS option by using  `"DELIMS="`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do ...
```

Also, your ECHO statement has an extra space at end that is causing the line not to match when you later test it in another run. If you remove the space then the 2 is treated as the handle for stderr. One fix is to add parentheses.

```
(echo Software name 2) >> C:\software-dist.txt
```

But there is a simpler and faster solution. You can use FINDSTR to determine if a particular line exists within a file.

```
:Step1
>nul findstr /xc:"Softwarename1" "C:\software-dist.txt" || (
  "\\server\share\%%F"
  >>"C:\software-dist.txt%" echo Softwarename1
)

:Step2
>nul findstr /xc:"Software name 2" "C:\software-dist.txt" || (
  "\\server\share\%%F"
  >>"C:\software-dist.txt%" echo Software name 2
)
```

The code is shorter and easier to maintain with the addition of a variable and a FOR loop.

```
set "file=C:\software-dist.txt"
for %%F in ("Softwarename1" "Software name 2") do (
  >nul findstr /xc:%%F "%file%" || (
    "\\server\share\%%~F"
    (echo %%~F)>>"%file%"
  )
)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I changed the delims bit in my original script to `for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\software-dist.txt) do ...`, however, it still did not work. However, the good news... your first script worked just fine ;O). Unfortunately, your second script did not... the **software-dist.txt** file keeps updating with 2 additional lines. What I noticed is that in the first script, the entries in the **software-dist.txt** are without double quotes. In the second script, the entries are shown as "Software1" etc.

Comment: What I also don't understand is your code for the installation `"\\server\share\%%F"`. This means that the name of the software is also the name of the installation file - right?

Comment: I have ammended your first script at little to [this](http://www.edv-089.de/downloads/stackoverflow/software-dist.cmd). Would be nice to get your second script working ;O)

Comment: @KerstinFischer - Your original code had an extra space in output. My 2nd code had unwanted quotes in `%%F` that are removed with `%%~F`. You will have to add some mods to code to fit your specific needs. See updated answer. If your question has been answered, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark in the upper left hand corner. That lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 rep points. Only one answer per question can be accepted.

Comment: Great - seems to work. However, the only problem is the line which does the installation `"\\server\share\%%~F"`. The setup .exe is never the same name as the application itself. Any way we can pass the correct setup.exe to each program? Also, some of the setups have variables (i.e. /Q /passive) which also need to be passed to the exes.

Comment: my original question / script mentioned that different software needs to be installed. Any chance of resolving this with your 2nd short code - which is really very nice ;O)

Comment: @KerstinFischer - If the string stored in the file is not the same as the string used to install the software, then I recommend my first solution, with one block of code for each software installation. You can easily hard code the specifics needed for each software.